# Extending ArrayList and Implementing IEnumerable - Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I need a data type that implements the IEnumerable interface but also allows for removal/insertion of any number of elements in constant time.

Further, the data type must allow constant access time to a known element. Essentially what I need is a C89-style doubly linked list that implements IEnumerable.

One of my requirements is that I not iterate over the data more than once.

I considered (and am working on) creating a class which extends ArrayList and implements the IEnumerable interface, but I'm concerned there's a cleaner or better way.

This all came about because one of the input variables to the code I'm working on is of type IEnumerable (and I can't change that).

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to achieve the functionality I've described without creating a separate class or iterating over every element?
2. If the answer to 1 is no, what are the broad steps I should take in creating the class I've described?

Thank you!

-------Edit-------

The main goal of this algorithm is to group elements together based on certain criteria (proprietary, hence no code, sorry!!!). To do this, the algorithm creates a separate list, and for each "parent" record created, copies (or (edit) ideally moves, which is faster!) records specified by the algorithm as children of the parent node. Sorry about not being more clear with this; I was working 2pm->10pm EST last night.

Comment: Doesn't `List<T>` already provide what you want?

Comment: No, if you see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx) List<T>.GetRange requires n time to retrieve any number of elements; I'll edit the question to make that requirement more clear!  :)

Comment: Although the text "Further, the data type must allow constant access time to a known element. Essentially what I need is a C89-style doubly linked list that implements IEnumerable." seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: How can you have a doubly-linked list and constant element access time?

Comment: I just realized this is impossible... I can't reference the elements using indexing while simultaneously manipulating their positions...that would break the indexing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65889/discussion-between-furiousfolder-and-enigmativity).

Comment: Care to explain why you downvoted my question? It violates none of the stack overflow requirements. The fact that it is impossible to answer (thanks to Enigmativity for pointing this out) does not distract from its historical use to someone seeking the same solution.

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is no (practical) solution to your issue.  There is a "normal" doubly-linked list class as [`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx).  How does C89-style differ?

Comment: Andrew, C89 would allow you to move the next/previous pointers directly. Even if you used sizeof to move your pointers to the correct location, implementing this is C# would require the use of unsafe (see my answer). Further, since the C# LinkedList doesn't have GetRange (and can't since that would require it to keep track of indexing) any time you want to remove/copy k elements, you'd have to use k time. For the entire list, this sums to 2N

Comment: @FuriousFolder: I guess you mean constant-time *splice* then.  *Splice* is a separate operation from *element access*.  Linked lists don't have constant time lookup.  I guess by "known element" you mean you have a reference to the node containing it?

Comment: Regarding your edit, it almost sounds like you actually need some kind of index lookup on whatever criteria you are using to associate items with their parent nodes.  Depending what you are trying to do, Linq _may_ already have operators for this task, but it is difficult to say without more information.  As far as "copying or moving," if the items are of reference types, you're adding references either way, and there may not be an advantage to "moving" rather than "copying."

Comment: @Andrew, why do you say there may not be an advantage over referencing vs copying? In a doubly linked list environment, copying k elements requires k-time, whereas moving requires a single operation. I forgot to add ideally, indicating that the algorithm doesn't move the elements right now; it copies them.
I miss C89... this would be a lot simpler in it.

Comment: I read your edit as wanting to create references from parent nodes to child nodes.  That wouldn't require moving _or_ copying any actual elements, just adding references (again, presuming reference types).  If you are back in doubly-linked-list land, then yes, what you say makes sense.  I think I'm still not completely understanding the problem -- I know the code is proprietary, but an anonymized code sample may clarify things.

Comment: I'll spin some up this evening for the sake of posterity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure what this c89 style linked-list is supposed to do; some of the things like insertion and removal of multiple elements in O(1) definitely seem impossible except in very constrained situations.

Nevertheless, it is simple to convert such a data structure using pointer manipulation to a managed c# structure without pointers: Allocate an array and pretend its array indices are pointers.

so instead of `malloc(100 *Size_Of_Node)`
you would do  `nodes[]= new Node[100];`

and inside each node, instead of a `Node* next` and a `Node* prev` you would store an `int next` and an `int prev`, and then access neighbouring nodes by `Node nextNode = nodes[currentNode.next]`.

This allows you all the possibilities of direct pointer manipulation at the cost of one additional layer of indirection when accessing each element.

If you use a `List<Node>` instead of an array as the backing storage, you could also grow its size as needed, instead of allocating it beforehand.

In order to use this custom C89 style linked list in places where you need an IEnumerable, all you need to do is implement IEnumerable for this structure like this (incomplete):

```
public class LinkedListC89<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
   private class Node<T>
   {
      public int Prev;
      public int Next;
      public T Value;
   }
   private Node[] nodes;
   private Node first;

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
        Node curNode = first;

        While (curNode != null)
        {
            yield return curNode.Value;
            if (curNode.Next>nodes.Length) yield break;
            curNode = nodes[curNode.Next]
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Enigmativity for showing me this is impossible.

Since indexing requires that elements stay in order and that they are not removed, reindexing the list would require N-(N-k) time. (where N is the length of the list and k is the number of elements). Using a strictly linkedlist solution would still require k time to iterate over all the k elements.

The only solution I see would be to implement a type which uses a C89 style of doubly linked list as well as sizeof to jump over the k elements to be removed to the next element (so as to preserve the integrity of the list). This would then allow N time for the list to be processed. It would also require 2N memory.

It is worth pointing out though that such a solution would have to take advantage of the "unsafe" C# keyword. This means that any methods calling this method would also have to be marked unsafe, all the way up to main. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for an idea of why this is a rather bad route to take.

Comment: You can do this without unsafe, if instead of storing pointers to memory locations inside the linkedList, you instead store indices to a backing array/list. Nevertheless, I don't see how you can remove multiple elements in constant time. Jumping over elements works as long as you have not removed anything from the list before, but once the list has gaps, you need to traverse all elements you want to remove, in order to skip elements that were removed previously.

Comment: In a C89 doubly linked list, you have back and next pointers on your nodes. Suppose you have a->b->c->d (with back pointers as well). Setting a's next pointer to d, and d's back pointer to a requires 2 operations, or constant time. Using a cursor pointer, where int* cur = &a; cur+=sizeof(MyNodeType)*numberEles; cur.back=&a; a.next=&cur;. This allows constant time removal/additions.

Comment: After writing out a quick example using a backing array, you are correct. This would work, but only in an environment where I could use memory manipulation. Otherwise, to determine when the list has found the end of the elements to be removed, it would require numberEle's steps.

Comment: Setting the two pointers requires 2 operations, true; but finding "a" and "d" always requires n operations.  You need to traverse the linked list from a to d; you cannot jump over the elements in between by just knowing their size in memory, since the elements are not neccesarily consecutive in memory after previous removal or insertions. I don't see how you can get around that using memory manipulation.

Comment: @HugoRune In the hypothetical C89 2x LinkedList case, you can, assuming you 1. Reserve a contiguous amount of memory using malloc, and 2. only iterate over the list once. I failed to indicate that both of these conditions would have to be true; my apologies for this oversight. You are correct that in C# the first condition would likely not (probably never) be true, and so my method wouldn't work.

Comment: Seems like this cannot work with insertions, only removals, unless each insertion is preceded by an equal or larger removal in the same location. However if this works, I disagree that it will not work in c#: Everything you can do with malloc, you can simulate by allocating an array and pretending the array indices are pointers to memory. So: 1) allocate an array `nodes[]` of sufficient size. 2) Create a custom linked-list that stores array indices instead of pointers for `prev` and `next`. 3) traverse your linked-list by `nextNode = nodes[curNode.next]` instead of `nextNode = curNode.next`.

Comment: Oh, I see! To generate a returnable list object would require another iteration over the indexing array though, right?

Comment: If you want to return a `List<t>`, you would have to create a copy of your custom LinkedList, thereby iterating over it (over the LinkedList, not the backing array). If you just want an `IEnumerable<T>`, then your LinkedList only needs to implement IEnumerable using `yield`. The code that consumes this IEnumerable would of course cause another iteration over the LinkedList, there is no way around using an IEnumerable besides iterating over it.

Comment: Thank you, HugoRune. You've been very helpful. Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not meet your constant-time requirements, an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) based on something along the lines of a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) would have logarithmic-time insertions and removals.  Finding an element's index and finding an element by index are both logarithmic-time operations as well.  Five seconds on Google did not reveal any obvious open-source .NET implementations of order statistic trees, but writing your own shouldn't be horribly difficult.  You may decide not to back the collection strictly with a B+ tree, but the idea is that sequential access should still be possible.

Such a class would properly implement [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx), which is of course derived from `IEnumerable<T>`.  It sounds like you are aware that `IEnumerable<T>` on its own guarantees you very little.  If your code is passed an `IEnumerable<T>` that is not actually your order-statistic-tree class, you would have to create the order-statistic tree from the `IEnumerable<T>`, which (I think) is an `O(n ln n)` operation.  I am presuming that the `IEnumerable<T>` is finite, which is also [not guaranteed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).  It sounds like you are not concerned about infinite collections, though.  In addition to the requirements of `IList<T>`, you would want to add specific range operations for insertion and deletion (like `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`) that would be optimized for your use case.

This solution has the advantage of not needing `unsafe`, and it does not directly present the "but once the list has gaps" problem that @HugoRune mentioned in his comment to your answer.

Also, don't bother inheriting from `ArrayList`.  If you want to use an `ArrayList` -- or any other collection implementation -- to store your items, do so by delegation to an internal instance of the collection implementation.

Comment: I considered such a tree initially, but given that we never need to revisit each node after adding its children, I couldn't justify the time needed to iterate over the list twice. This would work though, but would require 2*n*log(n) time, which is worse than 2*n :)

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to iterate the list twice, though you are correct that initially building the tree may be more expensive than whatever alternative you are pursuing.